# Save value in byte of var in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I want to make a program that takes 10 characters from the user and saves them in a vector *DATA*, but I get the error

> can't add relative quantities

in `mov byte ptr DATA[pos], al` when I try to store the value.
How to solve this error?

```
 .model small
 .stack 100h
 .data
   DATA db 10 dup(?)
   cont db 010h
   pos db 0h
   msg db 10,13,7, 'Input: ', '$'

.code
 mov ax, @data
 mov ds, ax
 mov es, ax

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg
int 21h

cicle:  
  mov ah, 01h
  int 21h

  mov byte ptr DATA[pos], al   ;Save ASCII char in position pos in DATA

  inc pos
  dec cont 
jnz cicle
```

Comment: `DATA[pos]` does not mean what you seem to think it means. What it actually means is `[address of DATA + address of pos]`. You seem to want something like `mov bx,pos`, `move byte ptr [DATA+bx],al`

Comment: Make that `movzx bx,byte ptr pos` instead of `mov bx,pos`, since `pos` is a byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing modes that can load an index from memory.  Keep your index in a register like a normal person, that's what registers are for.

Or use a pointer increment and compare against an end-pointer.

You don't need static storage for `cont` either.  It's an assemble-time constant which you've chosen to hard-code as `10h`, i.e. 16, which is larger than the amount of space you reserved for DATA...  So that's just a bug which goes away if we simply put a label after DATA, or let the assembler calculate its size.

Comparing a register against a label uses the *address* as an immediate, not loading a value from memory.

```
 .model small
 .stack 100h
 .data
   DATA db 10 dup(?)
   DATA_END:
   data_size = $ - DATA       ; or if you want the size in bytes, you can do this

   msg db 10,13,7, 'Input: ', '$'


.code
 mov ax, @data
 mov ds, ax
 mov es, ax

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET msg    ; There's no reason to use LEA for putting static addresses into registers, except with x86-64 RIP-relative addressing.  MOV is shorter and more efficient.
int 21h


mov  di, OFFSET DATA
mov  ah, 01h         ; we can hoist this out of the loop because we don't destroy AH

cicle:               ; do {
  int  21h

  mov  [di], al         ;Save ASCII char into DATA

  inc  di
  cmp  di, OFFSET DATA_END
  jb   cicle         ; }while(p < end_pointer);
```